# Are the words "apparatus" and "equipment" synonyms?

Tags: teaching-lab

Are the terms "apparatus" and "equipment" synonyms, within a chemistry or physics laboratory? If not, what are distinguishing factors?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about semantics.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYuF6.png

Comment: @Mithoron I foresaw this claim and hence the context. It might not seem to be a very technically relevant topic.. but FYI there are students of science who find such questions to be .. well .. intriguing..

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon I guess that answers the question in a very general sense including the ‘lab’ scenario.. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Within a lab they are synonymous. But if you consider in general, apparatus refer to non-machines. Equipment on the other hand can be divided into a couple of sections:

1. Non-mechanical which can be things like kitchen equipment, measuring cups, knives (all hand tools)
2. Mechanical machines which are things like sewing machines, mechanical diggers.
3. Powered machines that are powered by either gas, steam or electricity.